# What is Pro-Europeanism?

Tags: parties, europe

I was reading a list of some political parties and one of them supports the idea of "Pro-Europeanism". What is that and is it supported by a lot of people?

Comment: Could you add a source?

Comment: Seems like just a convinient label for being "more" pro-EU integration. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-Europeanism . Presumably the opposite of being Euro-Skeptic

Answer (score 4):

Pro-Europeanism is a political category applied to a person, a party or an organization supporting the idea of European integration, mainly though not exclusively through the European Union (EU). Pro-Europeans or pro-Europeanists generally support further integration, specifically in the context of political argument over the current and future status of the EU and its policies.

source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-Europeanism)

However, Main goal of pre-European parties depends where they are.

**In EU,** pro-European political parties support the Idea of EU. They may think about some modernization but not leaving this union.

In **east European non-EU countries** (like Georgia, Ukraine etc) pro-European political parties saying that country should became member of EU and government should do everything for that.

In **central European non-EU countries** (like Switzerland, Norway) such political parties support more integration to EU but not necessary becoming member.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Your first paragraph has "(wiki)" at the end, which I assume means it's in some way sourced from Wikipedia. Would you mind changing that to a link so that other users can more conveniently evaluate your source?